Can I use Tanh before softmax?
I am researching the use of neural networks for binary classification tasks of financial data. The output result is two-dimensional, such as [[0.5,0.5], [0.1,09]]. In the case of only 2000 small samples, I found training very difficult and often encountered situations where loss and accuracy did not decrease. However, when I added Tanh before the softmax of the output layer, the results performed very well. Why is this happening?
I asked GPT4 and it told me that doing so would limit the output of the basic model, and since the output is symmetric, it may be helpful for unstable models.
Renew：I'm very sorry for the ambiguity in my expression.
When I say it performs better, I mean that when I train the model, without this tanh layer, the model often fails to train, resulting in loss and accuracy remaining completely unchanged in 1000 epochs. I think this may be due to the initialized model outputting a very extreme out put, because the model constantly prompts for the appearance of longlong_scalars type，maybe i need try other way to initialize my model?

Side note: GPT-4 is not animate, so “he” is not the right pronoun. You want to use “it”.

Why use softmax at all? If you have 2 outputs and they are non-negative and must sum to 1, then the sigmoid function seems like the better tool. You can compute the second value as one minus the first value.

In what sense did "the results perform very well"?

Many suggestions on how to debug a neural network that doesn’t learn: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352036/22311

The softmax, logistic, and tanh are all flavors of functions that map the reals onto a bounded interval. It makes no practical sense to compound these functions, except that it changes the functional form relating the input to output - but the same could be said of adding quadratic terms, or just creating a new function.
More than likely, your model performance is based on something like a mean-squared error, and by applying two monotonic, bounded functions the output has a much smaller variance, making mean-squared error artificially small because the scale of the output is nonsensical.

Thank you for your answer! The loss function I use is cross entropy. When I say it performs better, I mean that when I train the model, without this tanh layer, the model often fails to train, resulting in loss and accuracy remaining completely unchanged in 1000 epochs. I think this may be due to the initialized model outputting a very extreme out put, because the model constantly prompts for the appearance of longlong_scalars type，maybe i need try other way to initialize my model?

You can. Technically, you introduce a new kind of output activation function by composing two functions.
I would doubt that if generally performs better, unless shown explicitly on a lot of different data sets.
Nonetheless, in GLMs people did successfully argue about different output activation functions (see e.g. the discussion on logit, probit, clog-log ... How to choose the link function when performing a logistic regression? )
